# didSet is always called when initializing a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, observers, didset

I have a custom UITableViewCell with the following:

- a computed property called `quantityCount` with `didSet`.
- Array.

didSet has a condition, if the current `quantityCount > oldValue`, I will increase append to my array.
if the `oldValue > quantityCount` I will remove the last element of the array.

Here is an example:

```
private var quantityCount = 1 {
    didSet {
        if quantityCount > oldValue {
            self.myArray?.append(quantityCount)
        } else if oldValue > quantityCount {
            customizationContainers?.removeLast()
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the user can open the UITableView that owns this cell as many times as he wants. This causes an issue with me because when the cell gets initialized, the `oldValue == 1` which makes the first condition is true and `myArray` is increased by one.

**So my question is:**
I don't want to get the `didSet` called when the cell gets initialized. How to go around that?

Comment: Set a boolean to false, check if this bool is true before to run the condition, and if is false don’t do anything and set the variable to true, I’m not sure to understand your question so I didn’t post an answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple problems from my perspective. The first problem is that you are doing too much magic with the didSet for your quantityCount. Your code would be simpler and easier to understand if just removed the didSet implementation entirely and you instead called a function to append and remove values from myArray. Think about like this, another developer setting quantityCount would have no idea that they altering an array simply by updating the value of a primitive int.

Another issue, is the if conditions in your didSet implementation. They are hard to understand as well in my opinion

I would at least change you conditions in your didSet to the following, it may help you debug and solve the current problem you are trying to solve:

```
    if quantityCount == oldValue {
        return
    }

    if quantityCount > oldValue {
        //do something because quantityCount is greater than oldValue
    } else {
        //do something here because quantityCount is less than but not equal oldValue
    }
```